# jQuery changing contents of table data based on table data's class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following table that is populated with data taken from a database at runtime:

```
                while($stmt -> fetch()){
                //While there is still data being fetched, make the table rows below
                    echo "<tr data-id='$matchid'><td>
<img class='delete_imgs' data-id='$matchid' src='Images/delete_icon.png'>
<img class='edit_imgs' data-id='$matchid'src='Images/edit_icon.png'></td>
                            <td id='hero_column$matchid'>$hero</td>
                            <td id='result_column$matchid'>$result</td>
                            <td id='gamemode_column$matchid'>$gamemode</td>
                            <td id='mmr_column$matchid'>$mmr</td>
                            <td id='confirm_button$matchid all_cons' style='display: none'><img src='Images/confirm.png'></td>
                            </tr>";         
                }
```

The important parts are the `<td>` lines. I wish to use jQuery to edit the contents of that cell. So for example, I have `<td id='hero_column11>randomdata</td>` (the 11 being its potential runtime value). How do I use jQuery to change the 'randomdata' into something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).find('td[id^="hero_column"]').html('new value');
});
```

I have include it inside `document.ready()` but you can insert it when you click a button or soething else

Comment: Thanks! How would I adjust it for the numbers after hero column. For example:

`$(document).find('td[id^="hero_column""+id"]').html('new value');`

I don't think the above works...

Comment: Weel, you wrote that id is runtime, in my code I select the td with Id that start with "hero_column", but if you want to pass an id you need to get it from another element, for example before the td or table you insert an input type hidden where you insert the id and after you get it like: $(document).find('td[id^="hero_column"]').prev().val(); in this case you get the prev element value is a solution but there a lot of solution @k4kuz0

Answer (score 0):

Try with:
    $('#hero_column11').html('new data');

You can include this in a `onclick` event on a button or a link.